# Doorkeeper 5.4.0 ArgumentError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, doorkeeper

I recently updated my app, from doorkeeper 5.3.3 to 5.4.0 but changes to `Doorkeeper::AccessToken.find_or_create_for` were made apparently, but I can't find anything in the CHANGELOG

so

```
@access_token = Doorkeeper::AccessToken.find_or_create_for(
  oauth_client,
  model.user.id,
  oauth_scopes,
  oauth_expiry_time,
  oauth_server.refresh_token_enabled?
)
```

returns now an ArgumentError

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 5, expected 0; required keywords: application, resource_owner, scopes)):
```

Has this also happened to anybody else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Doorkeeper::AccessToken.find_or_create_for`](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/blob/main/lib/doorkeeper/models/access_token_mixin.rb#L163) seems to expects keyword arguments instead of a simple list of arguments nowadays.

```
@access_token = Doorkeeper::AccessToken.find_or_create_for(
  application:       oauth_client,
  resource_owner:    model.user.id,
  scopes:            oauth_scopes,
  expires_in:        oauth_expiry_time,
  use_refresh_token: oauth_server.refresh_token_enabled?
)
```